# How to avoid error in my search function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted  to use this code to do multiple search function. But it occurs the way around an error:
Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/python/program2.py", line 359, in search_record
    result = cur.execute(sql,name)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

my code:

```
def search_record():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("osp_database.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        selected = db.get()
        sql=""
        if selected == "Szukaj wg...":
            messagebox.showinfo("Informacja","Wybierz inną kategorię")
        if selected == "Imię":
            sql = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE firstname = %s"
        if selected == "Nazwisko":
            sql = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE lastname = %s"
        if selected == "PESEL":
            sql = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE id_number = %s"
        if selected == "Miejscowość":
            sql = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE city = %s"
        searched = search.get()
        result = cur.execute(sql,searched)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        if not result:
            messagebox.showinfo("Informacja","Nie znaleziono szukanego elementu")
        else:
            for index, x in enumerate(result):
                num=0
                index+=2
                for y in x:
                    lb = Label(root,text=result)
                    lb.grid(row=index,column=num,padx=20,pady=20)
                    num+=1
```

I tried to replace the "%s" with "%{}%" and it  doesn't help. Another error occured:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/python/program2.py", line 358, in search_record
    result = cur.execute(sql,searched)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 7 supplied.
```

Comment: The problem is simple, for sqlite replace `%s` with `?`

Comment: nother error  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/Marcin/Desktop/python/program2.py", line 358, in search_record
    result = cur.execute(sql,searched)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.

Comment: try, `cur.execute(sql,(searched,))` and let me know

Comment: Yes it helped thanks you helped me so much !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: actually i did similar thing: searched = search.get()
        name = (searched, )
        result = cur.execute(sql,name)

Comment: But you lightened my brain :D

Comment: Happy to help :D

Comment: Would appreciate if you could mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Of course man!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a syntax error, with sqlite you have to use `?` as parameter maker instead of `%s`, which is used with MySQL, so replace that and pass in the values as a tuple rather than an expression by saying:

```
result = cur.execute(sql,(searched,))
```

Look at a similar explanation by @MartijnPieters

> Without the comma, (searched) is just a grouped expression, not a tuple, and thus the searched string is treated as the input sequence. If that string is 7 characters long, then Python sees that as 7 separate bind values, each one character long.